# is it possible to integrate Atlas mongo DB to the solarwinds?

Tags: mongodb-atlas, solarwinds-orion

I want to integrate atlas mongo DB cluster to solarwind for monitoring. These are the matrices I want to monitor from solarwind. Is it possible to do this ?

Mongo DB Metrices

Connections,Memory ,DB Storage,Operation execution time,

Hardware metrics

Disk IOPS(Input/output per seconds),Process CPU,System CPU,Disk space free,Disk space used

Answer (score 0):

The hardware stuff you will get with basic monitoring (agent,WMI or SNMP), though possibly not disk IOPS via SNMP.

There are two MongoDB monitoring templates provided with Server and Application Manager (SAM), one for Linux and one for Windows. 
Details - http://www.solarwinds.com/documentation/en/flarehelp/sam/content/sam-mongo-sw5644.htm 
The windows version uses powershell to access the database, using the mongodb executable with --eval switches, providing connections, global locks, network, messages, operations, database and other  statistics, along with a TCP port check and a service/process check.
If you know the correct eval switches then it should be easy enough. 
The Linux version does the same but with shell scripts.